# Suppose B is a compact set in Real numbers and A is a subset of B. Prove that if A is an infinite set, then A has a cluster point.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

So far I have that 
Proof:
Suppose $B$ is a compact set in real numbers and $A\subseteq B$.
I will do proof by contradiction.
Assume $A$ is an infinite set and $A$ does not have a cluster point in K.

I’m not sure the next step I know I want to show a contradiction but I’m not sure where it will come from yet. Is it sufficient to use proof by contradiction.

Comment: Proof by contradiction is perfectly fine. What is your definition of compactness?

Comment: @G.Chiusole my definition is A set B in the reals is called compact if every open cover of ask has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has no cluster point, then, for each $b\in B$, there is some $\varepsilon_b>0$ such that $(b-\varepsilon_b,b+\varepsilon_b)$ either contains no point of $A$ or, if it does, then that point is $b$ itself. Then$$B\subset\bigcup_{b\in B}(b-\varepsilon_b,b+\varepsilon_b),$$and therefore $\{(b-\varepsilon_b,b+\varepsilon_b)\mid b\in B\}$ is an open cover of $B$. Since $B$ is compact, it has a finite subcover. But then, since each $(b-\varepsilon_b,b+\varepsilon_b)$ contains, at most, one element of $A$, $A$ would be finite.

Answer (score 0):

I think this statement is not true. For example $B=[0,1]$ but $A=\{1,1/2,...,1/n,...\}$.

Comment: $0$ is a cluster point of $A$ -- so $A$ does have a cluster point in $B$ (not necessarily in $A$, as your example shows).

Comment: Oh so the point is A contains at least a cluster point of B. Thanks for your comment. Then the answer is obviously yes since B is compact and any sequence contains a subsequence that converges to the point in B. A is infinite set then we can choose a sequence from A.

Comment: Yes, it seems like perhaps the OP wanted a proof from the open cover definition of compactness, not using the subsequence property which, as you have noted, makes the result immediate.

Comment: How would you do it directly? Establish a 1-1 correspondence between A and  B  by some function say f and show A has a cluster point in it